# The maximum length of string input to gmp integer?

Tags: c, string, gmp

I am trying to implement a cryptographic function. It is requirement that my string input might be of 10000 bytes long. So in order to use along with the gmp variables (mpz_t) i have to convert this string input into a mpz_t variable.

The gmp (BigInteger) library manual says nothing about this:
What is the maximum length of a string that can be converted into an mpz_t variable?

mpz_set_str() function was the only one I came across. Would appreciate if some can throw some light into this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If there is nothing said by the library, there are two possible limits to the length of the array.  One is the number of elements in the array must not exceed the maximum integer that can be represented by `size_t`.  The other limit could be imposed by the hardware.

Comment: Technically, the size of the array can't exceed `SIZE_MAX`. `SIZE_MAX / 4` would be too many elements if your array elements was `long long`.

Comment: @Chris Lutz Oh, I stand corrected.  I assumed things since the question is about maximum length of a string that can be handled by the library.

Comment: I suppose if it's a `char *` then it would be `SIZE_MAX` since `sizeof(char) == 1`.